# Getting -2147483648 when solving expression with decimal

Tags: c

Here's the body of my code

```
int OP, NP, first, second, third, blankets, remainder;

printf("How many people are knitting blanket squares at the beginning of the week?\n");
scanf("%d", &OP);
printf("How many new people are knitting blanket squares each day?\n");
scanf("%d", &NP);

//formula
first = 1 + NP;
second = pow(first,7);
third = OP * second;

blankets = third / (double)60;
remainder = third - blankets * 60;

printf("%d blanket squares will be made this week!\n", third);
printf("You will be able to make %d blankets and start next week with %d squares.", blankets, remainder);
```

This is sufficient except for when I enter a decimal (such as .5) in the place of NP. When I do that, I get an overflow and it outputs the value -2147483648 for the first printf. Is all I have to do change the data type? Sorry for a very simple question, I'm very new.

Comment: The first thing you should try is to display the values of `OP` and `NP` immediately after reading them: `printf("OP = %d, NP = %d\n", OP, NP);`

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Stated alternatively: Is it possible for knitting people to be cut in half? Of course (read: I hope) not. C does not waste resources going out of its way to protect against nonsensical input that invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: CAPITAL NAMES are often used for constants

Comment: If you entered exactly `.5` as stated, when two integer inputs were expected, the first one fails at the `.` which is left in the input buffer, and `OP` is not read. The same thing happens with the input for `NP` - that `.` is still waiting to be read, but cannot because it is not part of an `int` value. Neither of those variables has been read, and since local (automatic) variables are not ininitialised, you then proceed with *undefined behaviour*. You must **always** check the function return value provided by `scanf` (the number of items read).

Comment: I'll be the pedant :-) and point out that @WeatherVane of course meant "read" in terms of _read_ from stdin and _written_ to the variables. In terms of variables, UB comes from _reading_ an object that hasn't had a defined value _written_ to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing floating point arithmetics with integers, could overflow the integers. That is possible, but unlikely. You also loose precision of course. You need to use at least `float` for this calculations.

**The real problem**:

1. Using `scanf()` incorrectly.
2. Passing a floating point value to `scanf()` where it expects an integer. It fails but you don't know, because of (1).

Using `scanf()` like that leads to undefined behavior, your variables `NP` and `OP` were never initialized. But you don't know that, because you didn't check the return value of `scanf()`.

You MUST check it, like this

```
if (scanf("%d", &NP) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, bad input, expecting an `int'.\n");
    // Now, `NP' is not initialized unless it was before calling
    // `scanf' so you can't continue using `NP' safely from
    // this point
}
```

The same goes for `OP`.

If you want floating point values (*and you do, because you say so in your question*) use

```
float NP, OP;
if (scanf("%f", &NP) == 1) ...
```

Comment: @Zatchary - If this answer solved your problem make sure to accept so other SO users can see that it is solved. Thanks.